# Sentry with helm chart on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, sentry

I am trying to set up the sentry helm chart in Kubernetes environment. However, I am constantly getting the following error:

```
sezer@optimist ~> minikube --memory 10240 --cpus 4 start
  minikube v1.28.0 on Ubuntu 22.04
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver
  Using Docker driver with root privileges
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Creating docker container (CPUs=4, Memory=10240MB) ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.25.3 on Docker 20.10.20 ...
    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...
    ▪ Configuring RBAC rules ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
sezer@optimist ~> helm install sentry sentry/sentry
coalesce.go:162: warning: skipped value for config: Not a table.
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: job failed: DeadlineExceeded
```

If I run the debug mode it only gives this output;

```
sezer@optimist ~> helm install sentry sentry/sentry --debug
install.go:178: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:199: [debug] CHART PATH: /home/sezer/.cache/helm/repository/sentry-17.9.0.tgz

coalesce.go:162: warning: skipped value for config: Not a table.
client.go:299: [debug] Starting delete for "sentry-sentry-secret" Secret
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:128: [debug] creating 61 resource(s)
client.go:299: [debug] Starting delete for "sentry-db-check" Job
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:528: [debug] Watching for changes to Job sentry-db-check with timeout of 5m0s
client.go:556: [debug] Add/Modify event for sentry-db-check: ADDED
client.go:595: [debug] sentry-db-check: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:556: [debug] Add/Modify event for sentry-db-check: MODIFIED
client.go:595: [debug] sentry-db-check: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:556: [debug] Add/Modify event for sentry-db-check: MODIFIED
client.go:595: [debug] sentry-db-check: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:556: [debug] Add/Modify event for sentry-db-check: MODIFIED
client.go:595: [debug] sentry-db-check: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:556: [debug] Add/Modify event for sentry-db-check: MODIFIED
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: job failed: DeadlineExceeded
helm.go:88: [debug] failed post-install: job failed: DeadlineExceeded
INSTALLATION FAILED
main.newInstallCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:127
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:902
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:87
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:225
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
```

I am using this repo;
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/sentry/sentry

I tried installing without changing anything just to be sure.

I would like to say in advance that all your help is very valuable.

I tried to do the installation both in the remote server environment and in my local environment.

Comment: Did you finally get around this issue? I have the same thing and I know the pods and deployment are actually created even with that message in the background. My question is more like if you create this locally, how do you create your ingress to access Sentry locally?

Comment: Still, there is not solution. I created a Github issue and waiting response.

Comment: I actually got this working now. My experience is really what @jwiller below mentioned. A few things actually: 1. My docker deskop isn't big enough and causing pods were unanble to be scheduled, hence the errors and I have to do a kubectl get pods to find out. 2. I forgot to create a Sentry database on my database instance. So indeed we need to do a kubectl get pods and look at the errors and fix 1 by 1.

Answer (score 1):

*First of all, only the helm command log is not enough to determine the error reason.*

This error occurs because the post-install job waits too long to be marked as successful.

Maybe the correct answer can be founded in the source repository: https://github.com/sentry-kubernetes/charts

But let me try to figure out:
The sentry chart has some [Helm hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) https://github.com/sentry-kubernetes/charts/tree/develop/sentry/templates/hooks with post-install jobs, but by the logs you provide is not possible to determine which one is failing.

My suggestion is to troubleshoot this installation, try again to run the helm install command, and in another terminal tab run some kubectl commands to try discover which jobs are failing, like `kubectl get pods` `kubectl logs <POD>`, more options can be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-pods/

Maybe the post-install job is trying to create a resource that doesn't work in your cluster or something else.